# Trying to delete directories with an 'X' as the 4th character in the name

Tags: python, shutil

I have a folder with folders inside that contain files so I know I need to use shutil.rmtree but choosing to delete the folders where the 4th character is an 'X' is throwing me off so do I need a counter? So far I have:

```
import shutil

for some_dir in 'dir_name':
    if some_dir[4] == 'X':

for x in 'dir_name':
    shutil.rmtree('dir_name')
```

Comment: `for some_dir in 'dir_name'` Why are you iterating over a string?  If you want to iterate over the contents of a directory, use `os.listdir()`.

Comment: Yes but I haven't executed it yet since I know it won't work so any help would be great! I'm a newbie in this so still trying to figure it out

Comment: I see that you are new here, as a kind of rule of thumb do try do present code that actually can run. And welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As shutil.rmtree(...) will remove entire directories, the sample code has its line commented out. I suggest testing the code until you are satisfied and uncommenting the line (removing "#") to enable shutil.rmtree(). The function assumes the directory names are provided as a list of names:

```
import shutil
dir_name = ['ThisX a test', 'This is a dir to keep', 'yessX']

for some_dir in dir_name:
    if len(some_dir) > 4:
        if some_dir[4] == 'X':
            print('Delete ', some_dir)
            # shutil.rmtree(some_dir)  # <- uncomment this line when you are ready
            continue
    print('Keep ', some_dir)
```

Comment: then use shutil at the end to delete the directories that had X as the 4th character?

Comment: I modified the code to show where you should add shutil, it is not at the end.  Make sure you understand the code before using shutil.